# How can I create a function that returns a dictionary which shows how many of each letter occurs in the string passed to the function?

Tags: python-3.x

I must create a function that takes a string of lowercase letters as an argument. The function should return a dictionary that shows how many times each letter occurs in the argument.

For example if the function is called with the following string:

```
s = "program"
```

The function should return the following dictionary:

```
{'p': 1, 'r': 2, 'o': 1, 'g': 1, 'a': 1, 'm': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this.

```
s= "program"

def func(s):
    vals = []
    e = 0
    dt = {}
    for ch in s:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if ch == s[i]:
                e+=1
        vals.append(e)
        dt[ch] = str(e)
        e = 0
    return dt

print(func(s))
```

It'll work.

Comment: Thank you this is very close to the output I am looking for however the values in the returned key have single quotes around them. Do you know how I can get rid of these?